What is the best way to encrypt SQLite file on .NET core and use it in Android?
I have been trying to figure out a way to encrypt SQLite file and I can do it from the .NET core. The file is generated right and I am also able to open it with the SQLite tool but unfortunately, I am not able to open file on Android. Somehow it doesn't work there. I downloaded SQLite file using S3.
I'm using this nugget package SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher.
We are using AWS lambda to generate SQLite file and here is how the code looks like
SqliteConnection sqliteConnection = null;

var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
{
      DataSource = "/path";
      Password = "test" // Set a password
};

sqliteConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
sqliteConnection.Open();

SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sqlstatment, sqliteConnection);
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 command.Dispose();

//code to insert


This works fine and I can generate an encrypted SQLite file. However, I'm not able to open a connection with the same file on Android. Please suggest something.

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnectionstringbuilder:  Password: Gets or sets the encryption key. Warning, this has no effect when the native SQLite library doesn't support encryption. When specified, PRAGMA key is sent immediately after opening the connection. -- so I guess that Android built-in sqlite engine doesn't support this ..., see https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/see.wiki how to build it yourself
